# What are some Models/Methods to reduce noise using environmental data?

Tags: time-series, linear-regression, data-cleaning, noise

I have a set of pressure datasets from a mechanical device that frequently moves around the country. I also have several sets of environmental data (Altitude, ambient temperature etc.) from those locations at the time the pressure reading is taken. The pressure data is very noisy, but we believe this noise should correlate to these environmental factors more than issues with equipment etc., so I’m looking for an unsupervised method to reduce the noise of the pressure data, using the environmental data (i.e Takes both sets of data as input, and outputs a denoised pressure signal). I can't share the data, but I made a mockup shown below:

[image: Mockup of pressure readings taken over the course of a month. Green line is estimate of linear regression model.]

Answer (score 1):

At first glance this looks like a multivariate linear regression type of problem - predict a variable based on the value of several other variables. Tensorflow/Keras has a good online tutorial here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression
This is probably the simplest way to get started.

IF this is actual time series data where there is a trend over time, possible seasonality, and the value at one point in time is dependent on previous values, then there are also a whole set of ARIMA/SARIMAX methods - https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html

Kaggle has a great introduction to time series methods here: https://www.kaggle.com/learn/time-series